# Difference between @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID) AND @UuidGenerator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

What's the difference between using

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
private UUID id;
```

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
@UuidGenerator
private UUID id;
```

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@UuidGenerator
private UUID id;
```

```
@Id
@UuidGenerator
private UUID id;
```

I tried all approaches and read the documentation, also I tested it with show_sql and generate_statistics props
And i don't see any difference

Comment: `@GeneratedValue` is from the JPA API, while `@UuidGenerator` is specific to Hibernate. There are subtle differences between how the UUIDs are generated, which may or may not matter to your specific application. Article: [How to generate UUIDs as primary keys with Hibernate](https://thorben-janssen.com/generate-uuids-primary-keys-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

As Jesper already mentioned in the comment, @GeneratedValue is from JPA API (javax.persistence), while @UuidGenerator is from hibernate-core.

Basically that means that using @UuidGenerator couples your code to Hibernate, which is one implementation of JPA. Using @GeneratedValue decouples your code from a specific implementation, so you could change Hibernate to e.g. EclipseLink later.